# iOS: Get the list of tags of subviews in main view

Tags: ios, uiview, subview

I'm trying to get just the list of tags in the subviews in main view. I know I can get the subviews information with:

```
po [self.view subviews]
```

But what I need is just the tag ID of each view. Any of you knows how can I get this list of the tags of the subviews?

Answer (score 2):

Or, easier:

`po [[self.view subviews] valueForKeypath:@"tag"]`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was looking for:

```
nsarray *myViews = [self.views subviews];
nslog (@"my first subview tag %d" ((UIView*)myViews [0]).tag);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the list of subviews, calling `subView.tag` on each.

```
for (UIView *subView in [self.view subviews][) {
    // Here you probably want to append the tag to an array
    NSLog(@"%i", subView.tag);
}
```

Comment: I was thinking it should be a way to do something like this nsarray *myViews = [self.views subviews]; nslog (@"my first subview tag %d", myviews[0].tag);